# how to create table in pdf document last page bottom using itext in java

Tags: java, itext

I have created table in pdf document using itext in java. Working fine in functionality wise.
But I need to display table as a below of document.

this is my code

```
PdfPTable datatablebottom = new PdfPTable(8);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setColspan(8);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell.setBorderWidthTop(5.0f);
            cell.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);

            if(msgfb.equals("1")){
                //document.add(new Paragraph(""));
                cell.addElement(new Paragraph(""));
            }else if(msgfb.equals("2")){
                //document.add(new Paragraph("Thank you for your business"));
                Paragraph pf = new Paragraph("Thank you for your business Thanks for your bussiness Thanks for your bussiness Thanks for your bussiness Thanks for your bussiness Thanks for your bussiness Thanks for your bussiness",BT_NORMAL);
                pf.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.addElement(pf);
            }else{
                //document.add(new Paragraph(msgfb));
                Paragraph pf = new Paragraph(msgfb,BT_NORMAL);
                pf.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell.addElement(pf);
                //cell.addElement(new Paragraph(msgfb,BT_NORMAL));
            }
            cell.setPaddingBottom(10.0f);
            datatablebottom.addCell(cell);
            datatablebottom.setTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.getWidth()-70);
            datatablebottom.setLockedWidth(true);
            document.add(datatablebottom);
```

Comment: Can you brief how you need to display?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the absolute width of your table:

```
datatable.setTotalWidth(document.right(document.rightMargin()) - document.left(document.leftMargin()));
```

Then you need to replace the line:

```
document.add(datatablebottom);
```

with this one:

```
datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()), datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()), writer.getDirectContent());
```

The `writeSelectedRows()` method draws the table at an absolute position. We calculate that position by asking the `document` for its left margin (the x value) and by adding the height of the table to the bottom margin of the document (the Y coordinate). We draw *all* rows (0 to -1).

Comment: I have replaced code as like above u mentioned. I got error as "Error 500 The table width must be greater than zero". I didn't get pdf page.this error came for document.rightMargin() - document.leftMargin() as zero

Comment: Oops, my bad, I confused the `Document` methods. I'll adapt my answer, but normally you should have no problem understanding the concept.

Comment: hi friend,it's working fine for displaying bottom of document but i need to increase width of datatable.

Comment: Hi friend,I got how to increase width of datatable.Thank you very very much for helping to me

Comment: @BrunoLowagie There is a small error here in applying the margins, cf. [this question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43810449/1729265). You might want to fix it and the example on the itextpdf site derived from this answer.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, can you put this on Slack? I have been traveling (India and Singapore). I can't do this right now, but someone else at iText might.

Comment: I will so so later.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, I wanna more space for footer in my document So I cant adjust my document bottom size, and I need only footer on my last page, If i use the above answer last Page content overlapping on my Footer.

Comment: I added the same code for my table and the table size is wider than the other tables. I tried to set the custom position but it didn't work. Any help? Thanks

Comment: I looks like this overlap the other content that are on the same page at the end of the page, how to force a new page if the content does not fit?