# Creating table in pdf on last page bottom (wrong official solution)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[This is official iText solution for creating a table on the last page at the bottom in pdf document.](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-bottom-last-page) This solution puts my table at the bottom of the last pdf page. Great.

Unfortunately, it causes getting my table more narrow too. And this is what I don't want. I have tried several hours to get that table wider again, but without success. I cannot resolve it. How to put table at the bottom in original size before moving? What is the best solution of this problem?

Picture of the problem

[image: Picture of the problem]

Before moving, width of my table was created only based on table.setWidthPercentage(100); Then it started to report exception that width of the table must be greater than zero.

table.setWidths(number of columns in my table);

I tried table.setTotalWidth() set on different value than zero and then overwrite it with that official code from iText. But without success. I am looking for some elegant solution of this.

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream("C:/radek-folder/calendar.pdf"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   document.open();

   PdfPTable datatable = createHeaderTable();
   document.add(datatable);
   datatable = createFooterTable();

   drawTableAtTheEndOfPage(document, writer, datatable);

   document.close();
   System.out.println("done");
}

private static void drawTableAtTheEndOfPage(Document document, PdfWriter writer,    PdfPTable datatable) {      
   datatable.setTotalWidth(document.right(document.rightMargin()) - document.left(document.leftMargin()));

   datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()),
   datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()),
   writer.getDirectContent());
}

   private static PdfPTable createFooterTable() throws DocumentException {
   int[] columnWidths = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
   PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths.length);
   datatable.setKeepTogether(true);
   datatable.setWidthPercentage(100);
   datatable.setWidths(columnWidths);
   datatable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(5);

   datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
   datatable.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlignment);

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       addCellToTable(datatable, horizontalAlignmentLeft, 
   verticalAlignmentMiddle, "Přehledová tabulka", columnWidths.length, 1, 
   fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular, cellLayout_Bottom);
   }

   return datatable;
}
```

Comment: I would guess the problem is that `datatable.writeSelectedRows` includes a margin argument, which I think is `document.left(document.leftMargin())`. Can you try passing in a different value for this arguement, like maybe 0?

Comment: I inserted(document.leftMargin() - 50) for example, and it moved with table to the side. I tried various values, but i havent found the suitable ones. 
In three days at work i will try zero :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I inserted(document.leftMargin() - 50) for example, and it moved with table to the side. I tried various values, but i havent found the suitable ones. In three days at work i will try zero :-)

You should try zero now!

Indeed, [that official sample](http://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/1825) and [the answer here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560605/1729265) that sample is derived from are slightly wrong when they apply the margins here:

```
datatable.setTotalWidth(document.right(document.rightMargin()) - 
    document.left(document.leftMargin()));

datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()),
    datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()),
    writer.getDirectContent());
```

because the `Document` methods `left`, `bottom`, `right`, and `top` themselves already apply the matching margin, e.g.

```
public float left(float margin) {
    return pageSize.getLeft(marginLeft + margin);
}
```

Thus, the recommended code effectively applies the margins twice!

So your method `drawTableAtTheEndOfPage` should simply look like this:

```
private static void drawTableAtTheEndOfPage(Document document, PdfWriter writer, PdfPTable datatable)
{
    datatable.setTotalWidth(document.right() - document.left());

    datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
            datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(), writer.getDirectContent());
}
```